# Align last row of flex container

Tags: reactjs

I have a flex container that I need the last row of items to be aligned with the first row vertically. I have used of styled-components module as a styling tool. also added link of image.

[My image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixZ0x.png)

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
`;
```

```
const SingleBlobContainer = styled.div`
  width: 40rem;
`;
```

```
<Container>
        {React.Children.toArray(
          blobsInfoValues.map((blobInfo, idx) => {
            return (
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
              <SingleBlobContainer>
                <ValidationWrapper errors={errors} valueIndex={idx}>
                  <BlobItem
                    {...blobInfo}
                    fieldName={props.field.name}
                    isDraggable={shouldRegisterDND ?? false}
                  />
                </ValidationWrapper>
              </SingleBlobContainer>
            );
          }),
        )}
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just delete

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

here is the result:

```css
.Container{
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
.SingleBlobContainer{
 min-width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
<div class="SingleBlobContainer">
1
</div>
<div class="SingleBlobContainer">
2
</div>
<div class="SingleBlobContainer">
3
</div>
<div class="SingleBlobContainer">
4
</div>
<div class="SingleBlobContainer">
5
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to keep a responsive layout with 2 columns, 3columns and event 4 columns

Comment: so you should just set min-width